# Number of Map Jobs created based on Data Volume

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Whenever we run any Map job on any volume of Data, by default certain number of map jobs getting created. I wanted to know the logic behind it.

> Consider the situation when I am trying to upload data on HDFS or
>   using sqoop to upload data to HIVE

- Is there some static number of jobs based on volume of data like
  Mathematical Formula.
- Is there some intelligent system which understands your data based on
  Supervised clustering algorithm and it group data in each of the Map?

I wanted to know exactly how Hadoop knows about number if Map jobs, I tried to find the answer in internet but I couldn't find the exact reply .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of map tasks executed depends on the number of input splits calculated.

The logic to compute the number of input splits depends on the InputFormat used in the MapReduce job.

One map task will be spawned for each input split, so if there are 3 input splits we will have 3 map tasks

You can create a custom InputFormat if you need to customise this logic in anyway

Have a look at the [Definitive Guide](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-7/input-formats) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Each file is represented as blocks in HDFS. The default block size is 64MB.

The (blks) no of blocks would be roughly equal to (volumne of data in mb) /64.

A mapper process is created for each InputSplit. By default size of InputSplit is equal to the size of the block i.e. 64 MB.

To honor the data locality principle the Mapper is executed on the same machine where that block resides. So the no of mappers would be equals to no of blocks.